# Webserver With Image Using C#

Tags: c#, html, image, text, webserver

I Have a Problem With Make A local Website That Can Be Accessed From other Computer in my Local Network

[image]

I want to Pass the image from picturebox and the text from `textbox` into the website.

I have used the code that I have found online but I have modified it.

Here Is My Code in the form:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Html_Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string TextToshpw;
        Machine Machine;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TextToshpw = textBox1.Text;
            Machine = new Machine(555, TextToshpw);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //  Machine.Update();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Machine.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code which I have found with modifications:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace Html_Server
{
    public class HttpProcessor
    {
        public TcpClient socket;
        public HttpServer srv;
        private Stream inputStream;
        public StreamWriter outputStream;
        public String http_method;
        public String http_url;
        public String http_protocol_versionstring;
        public Hashtable httpHeaders = new Hashtable();


        private static int MAX_POST_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB

        public HttpProcessor(TcpClient s, HttpServer srv)
        {
            this.socket = s;
            this.srv = srv;
        }

        private string streamReadLine(Stream inputStream)
        {
            int next_char;
            string data = "";
            while (true)
            {
                next_char = inputStream.ReadByte();
                if (next_char == '\n') { break; }
                if (next_char == '\r') { continue; }
                if (next_char == -1) { Thread.Sleep(1); continue; };
                data += Convert.ToChar(next_char);
            }
            return data;
        }

        public void process()
        {    
            inputStream = new BufferedStream(socket.GetStream());
            outputStream = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(socket.GetStream()));

            try
            {
                parseRequest();
                readHeaders();
                if (http_method.Equals("GET"))
                {
                    handleGETRequest();
                }
                else if (http_method.Equals("POST"))
                {
                    handlePOSTRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.ToString());
                writeFailure();
            }
            outputStream.Flush();

            inputStream = null; outputStream = null;             
            socket.Close();
        }

        public void parseRequest()
        {
            String request = streamReadLine(inputStream);
            string[] tokens = request.Split(' ');
            if (tokens.Length != 3)
            {
                throw new Exception("invalid http request line");
            }
            http_method = tokens[0].ToUpper();
            http_url = tokens[1];
            http_protocol_versionstring = tokens[2];

            Console.WriteLine("starting: " + request);
        }

        public void readHeaders()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("readHeaders()");
            String line;
            while ((line = streamReadLine(inputStream)) != null)
            {
                if (line.Equals(""))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("got headers");
                    return;
                }

                int separator = line.IndexOf(':');
                if (separator == -1)
                {
                    throw new Exception("invalid http header line: " + line);
                }
                String name = line.Substring(0, separator);
                int pos = separator + 1;
                while ((pos < line.Length) && (line[pos] == ' '))
                {
                    pos++; 
                }

                string value = line.Substring(pos, line.Length - pos);
                Console.WriteLine("header: {0}:{1}", name, value);
                httpHeaders[name] = value;
            }
        }

        public void handleGETRequest()
        {
            srv.handleGETRequest(this);
        }

        private const int BUF_SIZE = 4096;
        public void handlePOSTRequest()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("get post data start");
            int content_len = 0;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            if (this.httpHeaders.ContainsKey("Content-Length"))
            {
                content_len = Convert.ToInt32(this.httpHeaders["Content-Length"]);
                if (content_len > MAX_POST_SIZE)
                {
                    throw new Exception(
                        String.Format("POST Content-Length({0}) too big for this simple server",
                          content_len));
                }
                byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
                int to_read = content_len;
                while (to_read > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("starting Read, to_read={0}", to_read);

                    int numread = this.inputStream.Read(buf, 0, Math.Min(BUF_SIZE, to_read));
                    Console.WriteLine("read finished, numread={0}", numread);
                    if (numread == 0)
                    {
                        if (to_read == 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("client disconnected during post");
                        }
                    }
                    to_read -= numread;
                    ms.Write(buf, 0, numread);
                }
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("get post data end");
            srv.handlePOSTRequest(this, new StreamReader(ms));
        }

        public void writeSuccess(string content_type = "text/html")
        {
            outputStream.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
            outputStream.WriteLine("Content-Type: " + content_type);
            outputStream.WriteLine("Connection: close");
            outputStream.WriteLine("");
        }

        public void writeFailure()
        {
            outputStream.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 404 File not found");
            outputStream.WriteLine("Connection: close");
            outputStream.WriteLine("");
        }
    }

    public abstract class HttpServer
    {
        protected int port;
        TcpListener listener;
        bool is_active = true;

        public HttpServer(int port)
        {
            this.port = port;
        }

        public void listen()
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            listener.Start();
            while (is_active)
            {
                TcpClient s = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                HttpProcessor processor = new HttpProcessor(s, this);
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(processor.process));
                thread.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }

        public void End()
        {
            listener.Stop();
        }
        public abstract void handleGETRequest(HttpProcessor p);
        public abstract void handlePOSTRequest(HttpProcessor p, StreamReader inputData);
    }

    public class MyHttpServer : HttpServer
    {
        string Text;
        public MyHttpServer(int port,string Text)
            : base(port)
        {
            this.Text = Text;
        }

        public override void handleGETRequest(HttpProcessor p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("request: {0}", p.http_url);
            p.writeSuccess();
            p.outputStream.WriteLine("<html><body><h1>" + Text + "</h1>");
        }

        public override void handlePOSTRequest(HttpProcessor p, StreamReader inputData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("POST request: {0}", p.http_url);
            string data = inputData.ReadToEnd();

            p.writeSuccess();
            p.outputStream.WriteLine("<html><body><h1>MachineName</h1>");
            p.outputStream.WriteLine("<a href=/test>return</a><p>");
            p.outputStream.WriteLine("postbody: <pre>{0}</pre>", data);
        }
    }

    public class Machine
    {
        HttpServer httpServer;
        Thread thread;
        int port;

        public Machine(int port,string TextToShow)
        {
            this.port = port;
            httpServer = new MyHttpServer(port,TextToShow);
            thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(httpServer.listen));
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            thread.Start();
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            httpServer.End();
            thread.Abort();
        }
        public void Update()
        {
         //Some Codes To Update the Website
        }
    }
}
```

---

But I Don't Know How To Pass The Image or how to update the server. Please advise.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I believe you can pass it as a byte array, but it sounds easier just to save it disk then display it via location in the <img> tag.